# How to access model properties in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm trying to make some changes in an Visual Studio 2008 MVC 1 code, and as I have just dealt so far with MVC 3, by the way far from beeing a beginner, I'm struggling with this problem:

Giving I have a viewmodel like this, where putting the List inside the User class itself seems to me nonsense.

```
    public class Register {
      public User User { get; set; }
      public List<Options> Options{ get; set; }
    }
```

Would anyone tell me how, in MVC 1, in a view strong typed with the previous model could I access the User properties, ie I'm trying for example

```
    <div class ="row">
        <label>Mobile telephone</label>
        <%= Html.TextBox("Model.User.MobileTel")%>
    </div>
```

but it doesn't populate the fields when reaching the post method in the controller.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how is your viewmodel passed to the view ? could you snippet your controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the "Model." from the name.

```
<%= Html.TextBox("User.MobileTel") %>
```

or

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User.MobileTel) %>
```

Comment: Thanks, bhamlin. But that's the thing, removing Model doesn't work and as I'm using MVC 1 I can't use TextBoxFor

Comment: Hmm. Can you share what the html output is when you use `Html.TextBox("User.MobileTel")` ?

Comment: Sorry, bhamlin. Completely my fault, I had changed User in the model for frontendUser and was still trying to access with Model.User